# Google Drive Api deprecated ( Google play games -> Saved Games )

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-games, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I received an email saying that on December 9th all methods using **Google Drive API** will be deprecated.

Reading the documentation of the Saved Games (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames), they use **Google Drive API**.

Will **Google Play Games** also be deprecated? How can I solve?

Thank you.

**My Build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 29
        versionName "29"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Drive Android API Deprecation**

The Drive Android API is deprecated as of December 6, 2018 and will be turned down on December 6, 2019.

This API is deprecated. Clients must migrate to the Drive [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation) or another suitable solution to avoid disruptions to your application.

October 21, 2019    The Drive Android API is removed from the Google Play Services SDK distribution. Apps will be unable to build until removing the Drive Android API dependency, but existing builds will be unaffected. The Drive Android API public documentation will no longer be available.

Read more at
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

Comment: Saved Games is affected by this change?

Comment: You don't have to change anything. You are just using Google Android SDK and it's using Google Drive SDK internally. So we can't do anything and let's leave it to Google developer's they will do it for us and hope they will do migration plan for their own SDK.

Comment: @John You can track their internal drive API migration using Maven repo compile dependency list here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-games/16.0.0

They have to remove the drive dependency which is currently showing like
Android Package com.google.android.gms » play-services-drive

Comment: @PankajKantPatel So I assume Saved Games should be still working? A number of my players reporting the saved games not working, not sure if it's related to this issue or not...

Comment: Hi, @RichardFu I don't think this might be an issue. It should work for all users or not for all. Please check there might be some issue with your code. might be some issue with the code logic if you can reproduce the issue just share with me so I can help to fix the related issue.

Comment: I have the same warning. I ignored it for a while because I thought Google will work on it. But December 6 is getting close now. Anyone has some news about that?

Comment: @L3n95 please check migration guide https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation#migration

Comment: @PankajKantPatel but the migration guide is for the Google Drive API isn't it? But I am using only the Google Play Games API. I hoped that Google will migrate the Google Play Games API so that I do not have to do any workarounds.

Comment: @L3n95 yes you're right. They should do this first in their respective library before telling it to anyone 